# Fill html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say i have such html table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and have such string: `I and my dog)...`

how can i do, that javascript with jquery library iterates via my string, and append this string symbols to my html table so, that first letter `I` goes to td, where td contain 1 number, space go to second, `a` goes to td with 3 etc, i'm new to js, but must do this, how can i do this?

**how to iterate via string, and append letter to td with equal number?**

Comment: You should show us your efforts so far in order to give you pointer. Basically you have to select all `$('td')` elements  and then use `.each` to `do stuff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, iterate each character of the string:

```
for (var i=0, len=str.length; i<len; i++) {
  var char = str.charAt(i);
```

Then, find the `td` with the corresponding number:

```
$("td:contains(" + (i+1) + ")", $table).text(char);
```

Where `$table` is your table, e.g. `var $table = $("table")` outside of the loop.

The full code:

[→ Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNmR5/)

```
var $table = $("table");
var str = "I and my dog";

for (var i=0, len=str.length; i<len; i++) {
  var char = str.charAt(i);
  $("td", $table).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == (i+1);
  }).text(char);
}
```

This does not fully work yet because :contains(1) also matches 16. I'll investigate.

Comment: ok, just give advice, how to collect then this new table to new string, each tr, after tr, for example 
I a  I d I I y etc, and also how to space's in string change to slashes?

Comment: also you code didn't append to number's in table, it's replace it

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris I don't quite understand your first sentence. Do you want to construct a new string from each row and cell? You can easily replace spaces by slashes using `str.replace(/ /, "/");`. (I updated the answer.)

Comment: also if i have str = "   gfd    "  and write str = str.replace(/ /, "/"); i see "/  gfd   "   but must replace all spaces...

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris Add the `g` flag to the regex: `str.replace(/ /g, "/");`

Comment: yes, works :)   also what i write first, i draw in paint: ))) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/result.png

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris I appended an example to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UNmR5/1/ Basically, find all TDs and append their contents to a string. (Do you know that Paint has a 'Insert Text' feature?)

Comment: also last question, how to be if my string has two symbols, or even empty, how to change all this 16 symbols to slash?

Comment: use equals instead of contains: a la
$("td:eq(" + (i+1) + ")", $table).text(char)

Comment: @Calvin in last UPD there is no contain

Comment: so, could you help? my string must be 16 symbols, and all not entered symbols must be /

Comment: @Calvin But `:eq()` checks against the internal index of the found/matched nodes. That is **not** equal to the number contained in the nodes.

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris I didn't fully understand your question. Could you please come into the chat room? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40073/help-for-question-19620938 Chatting there is definitely easier than here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go pure javascript [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jay_harris/qXWLb/4/).

```
var str = 'I and my dog)..', // test string
    // get list of td elements
    td = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
    i = 0,
    l = td.length;

// iterate thru each <td> element
for (; i < l; i++) {
  // save the number in the current <td>
  var num = parseFloat(td[i].innerText);
  // fill the current <td> with the matching string index;
  td[i].innerHTML = num + (str[--num] || ''); 
 //  (str[--num] || '') this will catch undefined string index
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the OP (@ValdisAzamaris), but I thought it should be as in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNmR5/): enumerate the string, assign the character at position *i* to the TD with the content *i*.

Comment: yes, via poor js is good solution, don't delete it, but i want first to see with jQuery)

Comment: @ComFreek your right, i = 0 as element = 1 as str = 0; this `--` fixed the problem

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris pure javascript is significantly faster than jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data  = "I and my dog)..."

$("td").each(function(index){
   $(this).text(data[index])
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. This enumerates all TDs and then inserts the characters, so the first TD would get assigned `I`. That's wrong since the first TD in the DOM *does* not contain the number '1'.

Comment: @ComFreek Yup, you're right, sorry. I think Blue Skies' answer is the correct one.